# importing a csv file into mysql as BLOB

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, blob

I'm working on test scripts and I want to load the results.csv file into a database as a BLOB. 
Basically I want my table to look like:

serial_number | results |.

So one row for each device. My code would look like this for a device with serial number A123456789 (changed names and path for simplicity). The table is called test.

```
create table test (serial_number varchar(20), results longblob);
insert into test values ('A123456789',load_file('C:/results.csv'));
```

When I do this, however, the second column which should contain a BLOB, comes out containing NULL, with no exceptions raised.

If I open my results.csv file in notepad, then save as .txt file with no changes whatsoever, I get exactly what I want when I run the same code substituting ".csv" with ".txt" in the path. Basically it would also solve my problem if I could load the csv file as a text file.

thanks for anything you may be able to contribute.

Comment: It looks like you are on windows, but you file path has a forward slash. Could it be that simple?

Comment: It's not that, because when I import "C:/results.txt" everything works fine. MySQL is finding the file, the problem is it's trying to populate the entire table with the .csv entries instead of treating the file like a string